# Rails - solution for records-level acl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, acl

I find many plugins which implements access control under controller-methods level, but i have some special situation:

for example, we have PostsController#index

```
def index
  @posts = Posts.all
end
```

i want to get records with scope -> `where(:user_id => current_user.id)`.
This is simple, but i want to do this on acl-level.
Of course scopes and conditions can be much more complex, like -> 'retrive only posts posted in specific country' etc.

Comment: What do you mean by ACL here? The two examples you give still sound like scope composition.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest approach would be to solve that via associations and not additional plugins.

```
 current_user.posts.all

 country = Country.find(...)
 country.posts.all

 ...
```

A perfect balance of readability, performance, and flexibility.